# java web app cannot create log files on glassfish v3(using log4j)

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, log4j

As far as I can tell, it can write to console on production environment, it also can create log files on my local glassfish. Any thoughts on this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, check if log4j is configured correctly. You won't get any log files if you didn't ask for them.

Second, as ckuetbach suggested, check if your paths have adequate permission. If you have problems of this kind, you should see log4j's error trace in Glassfish's log files. They won't halt your application, since logging systems are supposed to be non intrusive, but a trace should exist. And from it, you will know what (if anything) went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be the filepermissions or absolute Paths
 in the log4j config.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

Put log4j.xml in domains//lib/classes.

create and permission log folder as expected by log4j config e.g. ${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/applogs/myapplication.log